# How to scrap my boilerplate

Tags: haskell, boilerplate

I'm using the [syntactic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syntactic) library to make an AST. To evaluate the AST to a (Haskell) value, all of my nodes need to be an instance of the syntactic class `EvalEnv`:

```
class EvalEnv sym env where
  compileSym :: proxy env -> sym sig -> DenotationM (Reader env) sig
```

Syntactic also provides a "default" implementation:

```
compileSymDefault :: (Eval sym, Signature sig) 
  => proxy env -> sym sig -> DenotationM (Reader env) sig
```

but the constraint on `sig` is unreachable in instances of `EvalEnv`, making the following (say, overlapping) instance impossible:

```
instance EvalEnv sym env where
  compileSym = compileSymDefault
```

All of my user-defined AST nodes are GADTs, usually with multiple constructors, where the `a` parameter *always* satisfies the constraint for `compileSymDefault`:

```
data ADDITIVE a where
  Add :: (Num a) => ADDITIVE (a :-> a :-> Full a)
  Sub :: (Num a) => ADDITIVE (a :-> a :-> Full a)
```

As a result, I found that **all** of my instances for `EvalEnv` look like:

```
instance EvalEnv ADDITIVE env where
  compileSym p Add = compileSymDefault p Add
  compileSym p Sub = compileSymDefault p Sub
```

This boilerplate instance is identical for all AST nodes, and each of the GADT constructors needs to be listed separately, as the GADT constructor signature implies the `compileSymDefault` constraints.

Is there any way I can avoid having to list out each constructor for every node type I make?

Comment: Unrelated, I'm not sure you should be passing a proxy to `compileSym`. It's not necessary, and complicates that definition.

Comment: @Carl If it wasn't clear, `compileSymDefault` is provided by the syntactic library. There might be some reason for it there.

Comment: Where is the class `Additive`? I can't find it in any of the `syntactic` modules, and neither can Hayoo. http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=syntactic+Additive

Comment: @Cirdec That was using numeric-prelude. I replaced the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, the boilerplate arises from the need to use pattern matching against each constructor to bring the required context in scope. Apart from the constructor name, all the case branches are identical.

The code below uses a `removeBoilerplate` rank-2 function which can be used to bring the context in scope. Two example functions are first defined using boilerplate code and then converted to use the helper `removeBoilerplate` function.

If you have many GADTs, you will need a custom `removeBoilerplate` for each one. So this approach is beneficial if you need to remove the boilerplate more than once for each type.

I am not familiar with syntactic to be 100% sure this will work, but it looks it has good chances. You will probably need to adapt the type of the `removeBoilerplate` function a bit.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs , ExplicitForAll , ScopedTypeVariables ,
             FlexibleContexts , RankNTypes #-}

class Class a where

-- Random function requiring the class
requiresClass1 :: Class a => a -> String
requiresClass1 _ = "One!"

-- Another one
requiresClass2 :: Class a => a -> String
requiresClass2 _ = "Two!"

-- Our GADT, in which each constructor puts Class in scope
data GADT a where
   Cons1 :: Class (GADT a) => GADT a
   Cons2 :: Class (GADT a) => GADT a
   Cons3 :: Class (GADT a) => GADT a

-- Boring boilerplate
boilerplateExample1 :: GADT a -> String
boilerplateExample1 x@Cons1 = requiresClass1 x
boilerplateExample1 x@Cons2 = requiresClass1 x
boilerplateExample1 x@Cons3 = requiresClass1 x

-- More boilerplate
boilerplateExample2 :: GADT a -> String
boilerplateExample2 x@Cons1 = requiresClass2 x
boilerplateExample2 x@Cons2 = requiresClass2 x
boilerplateExample2 x@Cons3 = requiresClass2 x

-- Scrapping Boilerplate: let's list the constructors only here, once for all
removeBoilerplate :: GADT a -> (forall b. Class b => b -> c) -> c
removeBoilerplate x@Cons1 f = f x
removeBoilerplate x@Cons2 f = f x
removeBoilerplate x@Cons3 f = f x

-- No more boilerplate!
niceBoilerplateExample1 :: GADT a -> String
niceBoilerplateExample1 x = removeBoilerplate x requiresClass1

niceBoilerplateExample2 :: GADT a -> String
niceBoilerplateExample2 x = removeBoilerplate x requiresClass2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't scrap your boilerplate, but you can reduce it slightly. Neither the [scrap your boilerplate](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate) nor the newer [GHC Generics](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC.Generics) code can derive instances for GADTs like yours. One could generate `EvalEnv` instances with [template haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell), but I won't discuss that.

We can reduce the amount of boilerplate we are writing very slightly. The idea we are having trouble capturing is that `forall a` there is a `Signature a` instance for any `ADDITIVE a`. Let's make the class of things for which this is true.

```
class Signature1 f where
    signatureDict :: f a -> Dict (Signature a)
```

`Dict` is a GADT that captures a constraint. Defining it requires `{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}`. Alternatively, you can import it from `Data.Constraint` in the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package.

```
data Dict c where
    Dict :: c => Dict c
```

To use the constraint captured by the `Dict` constructor, we must pattern match against it. We can then write `compileSym` in terms of `signatureDict` and `compileSymDefault`.

```
compileSymSignature1 :: (Eval sym, Signature1 sym) =>
    proxy env -> sym sig -> DenotationM (Reader env) sig
compileSymSignature1 p s =
    case signatureDict s of
        Dict -> compileSymDefault p s
```

Now we can write out `ADDITIVE` and its instances, capturing the idea that there is always a `Signature a` instance for any `ADDITIVE a`.

```
data ADDITIVE a where
  Add :: (Num a) => ADDITIVE (a :-> a :-> Full a)
  Sub :: (Num a) => ADDITIVE (a :-> a :-> Full a)

instance Eval ADDITIVE where
    evalSym Add = (+)
    evalSym Sub = (-)

instance Signature1 ADDITIVE where
    signatureDict Add = Dict
    signatureDict Sub = Dict

instance EvalEnv ADDITIVE env where
    compileSym = compileSymSignature1
```

Writing out the `Signature1` instance doesn't have much benefit over writing out the `EvalEnv` instance. The only benefits we have gained are that we have captured an idea that might be useful elsewhere and the `Signature1` instance is slightly simpler to write.

Comment: I had been contemplating Generics as a possibility, but I'll take your word that it isn't possible.

Comment: All you need to do to see that `GHC.Generics` can't derive a `Generic1` instance for `ADDITIVE` is add the line `deriving instance Generic1 ADDITIVE`. GHC will give you the error message even when you don't have `{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}`, 
`{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}`, and `import GHC.Generics`.